# Google App Engine - Unlimited Incoming Email?

Tags: google-app-engine, email

The google app engine pricing page mentions that a free account is allowed to send emails to 100 recipients. I'm planning on using it to handle text commands sent as emails, do they allow unlimited emails coming in to the server?

Comment: Not aware of an incoming limit, but you might be better pulling your emails from an email server IMAP/POP rather than making your GAE app as the email end-point.  Just a thought.

Comment: Well using GAE, it's easy to have it submit a POST request to my actual server when it gets an email, and my server just has a default un-configured mail server running on it. Is there any real disadvantage to using GAE?

Comment: No disadvantages that I can think of.  Was really just thinking about an alternative if there was an incoming limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They don't specify a limit, but each incoming email essentially gets turned into an HTTP request.  You'll run into instance hour limits when processing those requests, so it won't truly be unlimited.

Comment: Thanks! I have to think that the server would really have to be getting spammed to hit any kind of limit like that simply processing text messages.